# Minimum of two multidimensional matrices, with which matrix 'won' (contained the minimum)

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, octave, minimum

I have two matrices (size 4x4) and I want to find the minimum between the two. For example:

```
A = [ 3, 2, 4, 5;              
      1, 2, 0, 6;                   
      9, 8, 5, 4;                   
      0, 1, 0, 3 ];               

B = [ 1, 1, 6, 8;
      0, 4, 6, 3;
      5, 6, 7, 1;
      0, 2, 3, 4 ];
```

Now, if I did a `min(A,B)` in Octave, it gives me

```
[ 1, 1, 4, 5;
  0, 2, 0, 3;
  5, 6, 5, 1;
  0, 1, 0, 3 ]
```

Is there a way to get the matrix that 'won', by which I mean which matrix contained the minimum, in each element-wise comparison?

Like, for the first element of both matrices, matrix `B` won and so on. 
I don't want to loop through the matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare `A` and `B` to find out in which matrix the minimum occurred.
With `A > B`, you will get a matrix containing `False` if the entry from `A` was chosen, and `True` if the entry from `B` was chosen. By adding `1` to it, you will get `1` if `A` was chosen and `2` if `B` was chosen.

```
>> 1 + (A > B)
ans =
   2   2   1   1
   2   1   1   2
   2   2   1   2
   1   1   1   1
```

Alternatively, you can concatenate `A` and `B` to form a 3-dimensional array with dimensions `[4, 4, 2]`, where `C(:, :, 1) = A`  and where `C(:, :, 2) = B`. Then you can call `min` on this matrix `C` along the third axis. When calling `min` on one matrix, you can get the index of the "winner" directly as a second return value:

```
>> C = cat(3, A, B);
>> [res, idx] = min(C, [], 3)
res =
   1   1   4   5
   0   2   0   3
   5   6   5   1
   0   1   0   3

idx =
   2   2   1   1
   2   1   1   2
   2   2   1   2
   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Perfect! The 3-dimensional array idea is beautiful! Thanks a lot!